# How to setup a subdomain DNS proxy?

Tags: dns, subdomain

Hello I will get a access to a subdomain division.company.com and I will have to name where to point it in contract. I don't want request for contract update because where subdomain has point to every time I need to switch a server.

I am looking to have a top level DNS like control for a subdomain.

a) Do I use some kind of routing/proxy server?

b) Is there a way to have a dynamic DNS assignation (single time minimal configuration on the top level domain side)?

c) Is what I am looking for possible with DDNS providers like https://www.dynu.com/ ?

I tried using dynamic with a test domain but it did not seam to function properly.

On test domain I added CNAME DNS record b.a.com pointing to b.dynamicdns.com and then on dynamic DNS'es DNS records I pointed a CNAME record of [www.b.dynamicdns.com](http://www.b.dynamicdns.com) to a website's server then on website server side I tried [www.b.a.com](http://www.b.a.com) but it did not seam to work.

Answer (score 0):

Top level domains has to add NS (name server) records for the subdomain pointing to a DNS management provider

https://www.dynu.com/ has and add own domain where subdomain can be entered and configured but other providers should work too.

```
NS b.a.com NS1.provider.com
NS b.a.com NS2.provider.com
```

That will delegate subdomains DNS record management to it and will allow for full control of it. Including adding CNAME records pointing to any server.